# automatically using -v option for git remote

Tags: macos, git, zsh

I'd like to automatically use the -v option for the `git remote` command.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run this:

```
git config --global alias.remotes 'remote -v'
```

That will place a git command alias in your git configuration file. To use it, type `git remotes`. Unfortunately, you can't over-ride an actual git command with an alias.

Answer (score 2):

Add an alias to your shell commands, like this:

```
alias grem='git remote -v'
```

technically this should go in .bashrc, and you should reference that from .profile (or .bash_profile).

Then you can use a much shorter command, and get what you wanted:

```
grem
```

So, your .bashrc file (in your home directory), would contain all of your aliases, and then your .profile/.bash_profile (whichever you have) would contain:

```
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
   . ~/.bashrc
fi
```

Comment: The post is tagged with `zsh`, so it's reasonable to assume the poster is not in fact using Bash.

Comment: Ah, so it is. Add it to .zshrc instead :)